# OneDrive integration

Tags: android, onedrive

I have to share a folder structure from my application to OneDrive.
I have check for the sdk for one drive but in that sdk can share only files not the folder and there is no option to create folder in that sdk 
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-picker-android

Then I got this link it can create the folder in one drive and can upload files.   My problem is that I have to create the folders one by one and update their contents one by one.
Is there any other SDK for OneDrive to avoid this situation 
https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android

Comment: The OneDrive picker is for applications that only want to interact with a single file, similar to how `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` works, except the files that they would retrieve would only be from OneDrive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the OneDrive Android SDK available here: https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-android. The LiveSDK you linked to in your question is for an older API, which has been replaced with the new one.

While the OneDrive SDK lets you share files and folders, you still have to upload files one at a time. None of the current OneDrive SDKs let you upload multiple files at once.

If you happen to be working with other Microsoft services and, not just OneDrive, we recommend using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io). It's just like the OneDrive-only API, but includes other services, as well, and also has an [Android SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android).

Comment: I have already seen this library any documentation how to use this new API

Comment: Hi your Microsoft Graph API doesn't point to anything